# Getting the response discovery json for the client mocker

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to use the Google API mocker as described below in the docs. But for the Calendar API, not the Book API.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import HttpMock
import pprint

http = HttpMock('books-discovery.json', {'status': '200'})
api_key = 'your_api_key'
service = build('books', 'v1', http=http, developerKey=api_key)
request = service.volumes().list(source='public', q='android')
http = HttpMock('books-android.json', {'status': '200'})
response = request.execute(http=http)
pprint.pprint(response)
```

There is an example of the Book discovery json return value [here](https://gist.github.com/Bachmann1234/19fddfb983022218204a).

How can I generate or get the response json for the discovery Calendar API V3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [API Discovery Service](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/getRest) to get the discovery document for Calendar API v3.

Comment: The irony. I literally discovered this myself a couple of hours ago but didn't get a chance to answer my own question yet. +1 and accepted.